# Record/logging functions that the main thread called

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

A real project is really difficult to debug because it is really big and programmed according to the [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) pattern.

Is there a way for Visual Studio or another program to record the class or function name that is called by the main thread?

I tried searching, but the results were always Time Travel or Snapshot. They are not what I need.

Comment: What are *"Time Travel"* and *"Snapshot"*?

Comment: [Time Travel Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debuggercmds/time-travel-debugging-ttd-exe-command-line-util) (TTD)? [Snapshot Debugger](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/snapshot-debugging-with-visual-studio-2017-now-ready-for-production/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project is .NET based, you can use my [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) tool to record and view function calls.